# Execute Multiple Stored Procedures with Dapper .NET

Tags: sql-server-2008, dapper

Does Dapper.NET support executing multiple Stored Procedures at once? I have several SPs each with different set of parameters. I want to send a single call to SQL Server to execute all the SPs. Each SP returns multiple records.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
using(var multi = conn.QueryMultiple(
    @"exec foo @a, @b;
    exec bar @a, @c", args))
{
    var foos = multi.Read<Foo>().ToList();
    var bars = multi.Read<Bar>().ToList();
}
```

(code is from memory; apologies for any minor typos)

Comment: Is there some sort of documentation on dapper? How do you suggest i find functionalists included?

Comment: @Bill readme.md is a good start and covers all of these; it probably isn't complete though - I will see if I can add more breakout pages: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Readme.md

Comment: @Bill apparently there is a micro-ORM course that includes dapper. I haven't seen it.

Comment: I will check it out and give feedback. 10x.